# Match/Index/Vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vlookup

Trying to create a formula to search 2 columns of text and return value in corresponding cell to the right...so, if I have 4 columns, A & C have text (AA, BB, CC, DD, etc) and columns B & D have numbers (1,2,3,4,etc), I want a formula to search the text of A & C and whichever column the text appears, return the value in B or D directly to the right.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the columns A & C have unique text and that there are no repetitions, you can use `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"AA",B:B)+SUMIF(C:C,"AA",D:D)
```

Otherwise, `VLOOKUP` would work too:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("AA",A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP("AA",C:D,2,0))
```

EDIT:

As per barry houdini's comment, you can use:

```
=SUMIF(A:C,"AA",B:D)
```

for a shorter version of `SUMIF`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!...one more thing, how do it get it to return a '-' or 0 if nothing is found?

Comment: @user2839261 The first formula should return you 0 if nothing is found. For the second, you'll have to use another iferror: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("AA",A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("AA",C:D,2,0),0))` Could you please mark my answer as accepted if this helped you? ^^

Comment: You can simplify to a single SUMIF, I.e. =SUMIF(A:C,"AA",B:D)